# Hugging Face Sentence Transformers API is throwing "Internal Server Error" frequently

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, sentence-similarity

I am using Huggung face sentence transformers api for the similarity scores between two set of values.

I am hitting api multiple times, it is working for first 5 iterations after that it will start throwing Inter Server Error.

is there any way to control this API?